# Iterate through JavaScript objects to produce an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. One of the objects looks like this:

```
   obj1 = {
    name: 'rich', 
    email: 'rich@test.com', 
    date: {
        greg : {
            name: 'greg',
            id: 1234}
        }
}
```

How can I iterate through this array of objects (called usersArray) and add it to another array of objects (called usersArrayObj) with each object containing the name of the user (e.g. rich) and the name of the other (e.g. greg)
so that my end result would look like the below:

```
obj1 = {
    name: 'rich', 
    pairName: 'greg', 
}
```

I have tried to use hasOwnProperty and so forth but they behaving a little bit funky...

Comment: `obj1` doesn't look like a proper object literal

Comment: @NinaScholz: _"**One of the objects** looks like this:"_

Comment: is the key `11-28-2016` dynamic?

Comment: @NinaScholz that is generated from a today() function

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest how so? is it not an object that contains KV pairs and some of them happen to be objects that contain objects?

Comment: No it's not, what you have is a syntax error

Comment: update your question with a proper input data

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest my bad. now it is correct

Comment: is pair name the key or the value of name property? btw, you changed dynamic keys, the date to a fixed key `date`, which makes the solution easier.

Comment: Do you control the structure of the objects? If so, is there a reason you have the `date` like this: `date: {greg : {name: 'greg',id: 1234}}` instead of this: `date: {name:'greg',id: 1234}`? The latter is much simpler to access the name; the former repeats the name and provides an unpredictable key.

Comment: @Theworm: Do not change the question like that. Your edit broke _all_ existing answers. You can't expect an existing answer to work if you suddenly change the data structure.

Comment: @Cerbrus apologies. I was trying  to change it to make it easier

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array like this:

```js
var myArray = [
  { name: 'rich', email: 'rich@test.com', date: { greg: { name: 'greg', id: 1234 } } },
  { name: 'foo', email: 'foo@test.com', date: { bar: { name: 'bar', id: 5678 } } }
];

var results = myArray.map(function(item) { // For each item in the array
  return {                                 // Return an object,
    name: item.name,                       // Using the current item's name
    pairName: Object.keys(item.date)[0]    // And the first key found on `item.date`
  };
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: cheers, what is this line doing :  `pairName: Object.keys(item.date)[0]` I get an error saying: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Comment: why can I just do obj1.date.pairName ? it doesn't like that and I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'pairName' of undefined` even though date is clearly there?

Comment: @Theworm: Regarding _"undefined or null"_: What data did you enter in `myArray`? The way you formatted the question, my answer should just work.

Comment: @Theworm: Regarding _"'pairName' of undefined"_: There is literally no way my code can throw that error. What are you doing with the result?

Comment: I have changed the code in mine to get rid of the first Greg, do you see that?

Comment: @Theworm: See my comment on your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129257/discussion-between-the-worm-and-cerbrus).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to crate the new array

To select the first key inside the object `data` you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) that will return you an array of a given object's own enumerable properties. You can then select the first element `[0]`

```js
var usersArray = [{
  "name": 'rich',
  "email": 'rich@test.com',
  "date": {
    "greg": {
      "name": 'greg',
      "id": 1234
    }
  }
}, {
  "name": 'jason',
  "email": 'jason@test.com',
  "date": {
    "mickael": {
      "name": 'mickael',
      "id": 5678
    }
  }
}];

var usersArrayObj = usersArray.map(function(user) {
  return {
    "name": user.name,
    "pairName": Object.keys(user.date)[0]
  }
});

console.log(usersArrayObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you show this working with another object inside the array?

Comment: cheers. last thing before I accept, what is this line doing: `"pairName": Object.keys(user.date)[0]`?

Comment: @Theworm It is explained inside the answer + a link to the documentation. `Object.keys(user.date)` will return you an array with all the keys of the object `user.date` then I select the first one

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses ES6. Use `Array.prototype.map()` and extract the object (inside `greg:`) using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) (the the browser's support in the link):

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'rich',
  email: 'rich@test.com',
  date: {
    greg: {
      name: 'greg',
      id: 1234
    }
  }
}];

const result = arr.map(({ name, date }) => ({
  name,
  pairName: Object.values(date)[0].name
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's already updated to your new code. You haven't removed the `greg:`.

Comment: how about now then?

Answer (score -1):

for this case what you can use is `Object.keys()` JS function.

```
obj2= {
  name:obj1.name,
  pairName: Object.keys(obj1.date)[0]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [{
    name: 'rich', 
    email: 'rich@test.com', 
    date: {
        greg : {
            name: 'greg',
            id: 1234}
    }
}]

var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) newArr[i] = {
    name: arr[i].name,
    pairName: Object.keys(arr[i].date)[0]
};
JSON.stringify(newArr);    // "[{"name":"rich","pairName":"greg"}]"
```